# Tool for adding buildings to OpenStreetMaps by tracing their countours on satellite maps

Tags: openstreetmap

There is an OSM map of some city, in which several buildings are missing (see the OSM map and the Yandex map of the same place below - there are lots of spaces, which look empty in the OSM map, but have buildings in the Yandex map).

[image: OSM map]

[image: Yandex map]

I want to add missing buildings to the OSM map using a tool, which

1. displays the OSM objects over a satellite map (such that I can see what objects are present on the satellite map, but not in the OSM map),
2. allows to add new objects (ways) to the OSM map by clicking points on the satellite map and connecting them to a polygon and
3. allows to save my changes (coordinates of newly added buildings) locally in a file.

What tool are there, which support these functions?

Comment: The ID Editor (introduced in May 2013) does this on the OSM Website (in editing mode) if adding buildings add to the main osm database then export your buildings to local files http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/ID

Comment: @Mapperz Please submit your comment as an answer. This editor is the best choice for a cartography newbie like me :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The **ID Editor** (introduced in May 2013) does this on the OSM Website (in editing mode) if adding buildings add to the main osm database then export your buildings to local file

*ID Editor aims to be simple and friendly*.

[image]

Capturing Buildings from Satellite imagery (from Bing Maps) is the quickest way.

Contribute to OpenStreetMap and then extract the data you want by downloading to your local environment.

http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/ID

Answer (score 4):

The JOSM Editor ( http://josm.openstreetmap.de/ ) does that.